# ¿Ejecutar un script de node indefinidamente para consultar una DB?

Tags: nodejs, express, npm

Tengo unos scripts de nodejs para que hagan una consulta a una Db de mongo, pero lo que quiero es que ese script se esté ejecutando indefinidamente, quizá con un sleep de 5 minutos, y que si llegase a parar haya otro script que lo "reviva".

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer estos procesos? ¿Se crea otro script que esté ejecutando el servicio y otro script que supervice que esté activo el primero? y si sí, ¿Algún ejemplo?

Comment: ¿algo que lleves hecho?

Comment: @Chisko he encontrado sobre forever, estoy viendo si me sirve :D https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mas fácil seria crear un bucle infinito y que dentro se esperen los 5 minutos y después se llame a una función. con setTimeout no debería tener complicación, aquí se responde a algo muy parecido con ejemplos útiles.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar el paquete npm forever, este te ayuda a "revivir" tu aplicacion.

https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Comment: Hola @Eli. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por aportar. Quizás convendría agregar un pequeño fragmento de código mostrando como esto respondería a la pregunta. La idea es sumar respuestas de gran calidad en el sitio